# Использование Resources в WPF С# XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

К примеру в разметке XAML использую ресурс из настроек программы

`Image Name="fon" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Fill" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/background.jpg"/>`

Дело в том что в редакторе отображается, но после запуска исчезает.
Но! Если указывать локальный путь то всё работает.
Интересует как именно использовать файлы из Resources

Comment: А если так: `pack://application:,,,/Resources/background.jpg`?

Comment: И что значит «из настроек»? У вас должен быть в проекте каталог `Resources`, в нём файл `background.jpg`, и build action = Resource.

Comment: Такой-же результат (в редакторе видно, после запуска - нет). Использую в Visual Studio -> Проект -> Свойства -> Ресурсы и туда закидываю файлы. @VladD

Comment: Странно. А что появляется в Output?

Comment: @VladD Если это "Вывод" на русском то ничего.

Comment: Окей, а как у вас добавлен `background.jpg`?

Comment: @VladD повторюсь: Использую в Visual Studio -> Проект -> Свойства -> Ресурсы и туда закидываю файлы

Comment: Это неправильный путь с точки зрения WPF. Делайте так, как во втором комментарии.

Comment: @VladD и снова такой же итог. p.s. при моём способе файлы так же попадают в папку Resource, единственное отличие там есть обозреватель с миниатюрами тех самых файлов.

Comment: Properties->Copy to OutputDirectory =Copy Always[Copy if newer]

Comment: @VladimirH: Тогда с вас маленький воспроизводящий пример, потому что у меня работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

немного не то, так файл копируется в папку с собранным проектом и ссылается именно туда (т.е. если удалить папку находящуюся в корне exe файла, естественно файл не загрузиться или выдаст ошибку. Требуется в 1 параметре (обозреватель решений -> изображение -> свойства)  "Действие при сборке" установить в значение "Resource", а после в компоненте image в опции "source" в выпадающем списке указать данный добавленный файл тогда он будет использовать запакованный ресурс, иными словами на выходе получим один exe файл. Но бывает что "глючит", с чем связано так и не выяснил (

Answer (score 2):

Последовательность такая:
Visual Studio -> Проект -> Свойства -> Ресурсы -> Изображения

Добавить ресурс -> Добавить существующий объект

Далее кидаем на форму Image. В свойствах выбираем нужную картинку из добавленных ранее. Она отобразится на форме. Однако, если запустить приложение - ничего не видно. В обозревателе решиния находим папку Resource и выбираем наш файл с картинкой. Далее Свойства -> Копировать в выходной каталог устанавливаем "Всегда копировать".