# При запуске проекта WPF не отображаются элементы

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Добавил элемент (stackpanel и два image в неё) на форму (Приложение WPF.xaml), но при запуске проекта они не отображаются.
Проверил всё - Visible, Opacite,isEnabled, вездё всё ок.
Не пойму, в чём причина? Запускал с отладкой и без.

Код формы:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="515" Width="365" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Window.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF232D3F"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF1D222C" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF1D222C" Offset="0.483"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Background>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Name="Toolbar" Grid.Row="0">
        <Polygon Fill="White" Opacity="0.2" Points="107,0,115,7,249,7,257,0"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="25" Width="56" Grid.Column="2" Panel.ZIndex="10">
            <Image Height="18" Width="18" Margin ="5" Source="/Images/minus passive.png" Stretch="Fill" Panel.ZIndex="2" />
            <Image Height="18" Width="18" Margin ="5" Source="/Images/x passive.png" Stretch="Fill" Panel.ZIndex="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: Форма в редакторе]

[image: Форма при запуске проекта]

[image: Вот эти элементы]

Comment: 1. Всякие крестики и пр. иконки, в 2022 году пихать в виде картинки бред, уже давно есть векторная графика, которая без проблем используется на WPF. Вот к примеру целая [коллекция](https://materialdesignicons.com/) иконок вам. 2. Ваш пример не воспроизводит проблему если задать просто пути до картинки на диске, а это означает, что дело не в разметке, а в том, как у вас в проекте заданы эти картинки, ибо они должны быть либо рядом с .exe, либо иметь "Действие при сборке: Ресурс". 3. Не прибивайте гвоздями размеры, дайте свободу своему проекту, не `Height="300"`, а `Height="5*"` например.

Comment: видимо код отсюда - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkYB9gLzKxc , в чем проблема просто сравнить свой код и код на видео?

Comment: @Pekor, я просто и делал оттуда и код совпадает один в один, но у автора отображаются, у меня нет. Я считаю из-за разных версий Visual Studio, но решил уточнить)

Comment: "2. Ваш пример не воспроизводит проблему если задать просто пути до картинки на диске, а это означает, что дело не в разметке, а в том, как у вас в проекте заданы эти картинки, ибо они должны быть либо рядом с .exe, либо иметь "Действие при сборке: Ресурс""

Comment: @Pekor большое спасибо! Переместил иконки ближе к exe, - помогло.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ большое спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! Не знаю как указать ваш ответ полезным, знал бы - сделал!)

Comment: @Kordas Это не ответ, а просто комментарий по теме, не более. Хотите ответ - можете написать сами (правда если вам помогло указание "ресурс", то на это уже были здесь ответы, лучше найти дубликат и закрыть на него). Кстати, мой вам совет, не относитесь к автору видеоролика, что смотрите, как к "гуру", который все понимает, ибо помню он сам тут, на SO еще ту чушь городил. Анализируйте то, что смотрите и пытайтесь черпать из материала только полезное, правильное, а то вон, вы гвоздями заколотили все размеры, из за чего потом можете очень сильно пожалеть. Удачи в изучении WPF!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ угу, в одном из видео, где он делал приложение используя MVVM, он сделал переключение между Page'ами, создавая в ViewModel классы Page'ей (`Page Wow = new WowPage()`) и переключаясь между ними

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, учту ваши советы

Answer (score 0):

> Ваш пример не воспроизводит проблему если задать просто пути до
> картинки на диске, а это означает, что дело не в разметке, а в том,
> как у вас в проекте заданы эти картинки, ибо они должны быть либо
> рядом с .exe, либо иметь "Действие при сборке: Ресурс""
> Ответ принадлежит @EvgeniyZ

Разберём по пунктам оба варианта (рекомендую первый)

1. "Действие при сборке : Ресурс"

> Последовательность такая: Visual Studio -> Проект -> Свойства ->
> Ресурсы -> Изображения
> Добавить ресурс -> Добавить существующий объект. Далее кидаем на форму
> Image. В свойствах выбираем нужную картинку из добавленных ранее. Она
> отобразится на форме. Однако, если запустить приложение - ничего не
> видно. В обозревателе решиния находим папку Resource и выбираем наш
> файл с картинкой. Далее Свойства -> Копировать в выходной каталог
> устанавливаем "Всегда копировать".

Источник: [Использование Resources в WPF С# XAML](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520051/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-resources-%d0%b2-wpf-%d0%a1-xaml?noredirect=1&lq=1)

2. "Перемещение картинок ближе к exe"

> Если конкретнее, то переместил в папку
> /bin/debug/net6.0-windows/<сюда>  Там, где файл.exe проекта.

Оба варианта являются решением.Можно либо первый, либо второй использовать.

Comment: а картинки должны в корневой папке проекта Images лежать? этого достаточно или они должны быть Embedded Resource? раз это ответ, наверное надо уточнить эти моменты. вам удалось поправить ваш проект, в дизайнере и при запуске рисунки есть? в чем было дело? а то всем интересно

Comment: @АлексейОбухов спасибо, поправил ответ

Comment: да, понял что сделали. я сам так в других типах проектов делаю. Несколько замечаний: 1) у вас два ответа, похожих друг друга, есть смысл объединить их. 2) не все так просто, тут 2 варианта [файл в сборке и файл рядом со сборкой](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/3.3.php), у вас этот момент спутан, вы то рядом кладете, то как ресурс добавляете

Comment: @АлексейОбухов сделал, спасибо)

Comment: Хочу уточнить. 1) Копировать ручками и копировать при сборке в Visual Studio - это по сути одно и тоже. 2) [Понятие ресурса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/566707/223310) - это более сложное, чем просто файл, который где-то лежит. ресурс может находиться и внутри exe-файла